# Can't compile code for x86 but can for arm

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, identifier

I have a strange problem. I can compile my code for `arm` but can't for `x86` using gcc v 6.3 (and other also).
Here is an example code that causes problems.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <csignal>
 
volatile bool $run = true;
 
static void quitHandler(int __attribute__((unused)) signum)
{
    $run = false;
}
 
void setupQuitHandler()
{
    struct sigaction action;
    action.sa_handler = quitHandler;
    action.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND;
 
    if (sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask) < 0) printf("[SetupQuit] sigemptyset");
 
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &action, nullptr) < 0) printf("[SetupQuit] sigaction SIGINT");
    if (sigaction(SIGQUIT, &action, nullptr) < 0) printf("[SetupQuit] sigaction SIGQUIT");
    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, nullptr) < 0) printf("[SetupQuit] sigaction SIGTERM");
    if (sigaction(SIGABRT, &action, nullptr) < 0) printf("[SetupQuit] sigaction SIGABRT");
}
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 
    setupQuitHandler();
    while($run)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Do nothing! \n");
    }
}
```

Here is an [online example](http://ideone.com/q4wvrW) with gcc

This cause assemble error:

```
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
/tmp/ccEUYGVm.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccEUYGVm.s:19: Error: junk `(%rip)' after expression
/tmp/ccEUYGVm.s:19: Error: unsupported instruction `mov'
/tmp/ccEUYGVm.s:137: Error: junk `(%rip)' after expression
/tmp/ccEUYGVm.s:137: Error: operand type mismatch for `movzb'
make: *** [subdir.mk:26: main.o] Błąd 1
```

What is more strange I can compile it with clang. Here [online example](http://ideone.com/62g3UU)

I have tried gcc versions 4.8, 5.x, 6.3 (x- I don't remember) with `-O0` `-O2` and `-O3` parameters.

If I remove `#include <csignals>` also tried (`<signal.h>`) and all dependents there is no problem. But it's nice to catch 'INT' signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$` is not a valid identifier character. It's a gcc extension which may or may not work with every possible header file. Don't use `$` and the error goes away.

Comment: It's a bug in the extension then? Mad diagnostic!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition gcc is handling it quite fine, and passing the result to the assembler. Now it happens that $ has different meaning with different assemblers. I don't know if there is a way to escape '$' that binutils would understand. To let it "work" on x86, gcc could also mangle the variable name, but that doesn't seem so useful.

Comment: @n.m. Maybe u know why there is no warning? Assemble error isn't very helpful. (I am just curious).

Comment: Use -pedantic, get all kinds of warnings.